# How to update part of my document in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm just getting started with Logstash and Elasticsearch.

See the code snippet below. In Elasticsearch I'm trying to update `host` value to `Foo` from `Bhargav`

What is the curl command I need to use to make this happen? Assuming I'm running Elasticsearch on `localhost:9200`.

```js
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 15,
    "successful": 15,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 8,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "logstash-2011.05.18",
        "_type": "apache_access",
        "_id": "yyncoyOeTgij9awB13S4WQ",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "message": "134.39.72.245 - - [18/May/2011:12:40:18 -0700] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 200 1189 \"-\" \"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)\"",
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2011-05-18T19:40:18.000Z",
          "host": "Bhargav",
          "timestamp": "18/May/2011:12:40:18 -0700",
          "verb": "GET",
          "request": "/favicon.ico",
          "httpversion": "1.1",
          "response": "200",
          "bytes": "1189",
          "referrer": "\"-\"",
          "agent": "\"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)\""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "logstash-2011.05.18",
        "_type": "apache_access",
        "_id": "sMcXwrmTQzaiWW-zUSE7MA",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "message": "134.39.72.245 - - [18/May/2011:12:40:18 -0700] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 200 1189 \"-\" \"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)\"",
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2011-05-18T19:40:18.000Z",
          "host": "Bhargav",
          "path": "/tmp/access_log",
          "type": "apache_access",
          "clientip": "134.39.72.245",
          "ident": "-",
          "auth": "-",
          "timestamp": "18/May/2011:12:40:18 -0700",
          "verb": "GET",
          "request": "/favicon.ico",
          "httpversion": "1.1",
          "response": "200",
          "bytes": "1189",
          "referrer": "\"-\"",
          "agent": "\"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)\""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do it on a single document or a set of documents ?

Comment: I want to apply this `update` for all the documents based on the `index`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the only option would be to use partial update in [UPDATE API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html)

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
    "doc" : {
        "host" : "Bhargav"
    }
}'
```

But then this can be only applied to a single document.
There is a out of box for [update by query](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery/) , you can try that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, previously I have also found and tried the plugin but was confused because I was giving a wrong query. Now I have fixed my query.